# Linking libsrtp problems

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I installed libsrtp on my ubuntu machine according to the directives in read me, the tests worked fine, and the rptw utility included in libsrtp worked perfectly too. But when I tried to include srtp.h in my HelloWorld! program, it gives me an error that:

```
fatal error: srtp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Concretely, my main file is this

```
#include "srtp.h"

    int main()
    {
      return 0;
    }
```

My libsrtp.a is present in /usr/local/lib/lib

I used this gcc statement from [this blog](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-and-using-static-libraries-in.html):

```
gcc -static main.c -L/usr/local/lib/lib/ -llibsrtp -o main
```

I will be deeply grateful for any help.

Comment: It's not complaining about not being able to find the LIBRARY, it's complaining about not being able to find the HEADER. You also need a -I (that's a capital i) option to gcc to tell it where to look for include files.

Answer (score 2):

You've found your libsrtp.a , but where is srtp.h ? You'll need to tell the compiler where to search for included files if it's not in a standard location with the `-I` flag.

Perhaps you need a `-I/usr/local/include` or `-I/usr/local/include/srtp`

Note also that `-llibsrtp` is likely wrong, you need to give the name without the lib prefix. So that makes it `-lsrtp`

Comment: Thanks a ton, nos. If it is possible, can you link to me a blog that explains how linking works? I have looked for it but hardly found anything concrete.